# iOS - self.view.frame.size.width is 0.00000

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

I have a view controller (`SecondViewController`) with a method named `setupHomeScreen` that is called from another view controller (`FirstViewController`).  This method is called *after* `SecondViewController` is initialized.

Within `setupHomeScreen`, a `UIView` is created that I would like to have the same boundaries as the main view, which will depend on whether the iPad is viewed in portrait or landscape mode.

When the method is first called (which is on app startup), the view is completely wrong, and an `NSLog` output shows the `self.view.frame.size.width` is equal to `0.0000`.

If I navigate to `ThirdViewController`, and then back to `SecondViewController`, the view is correctly displayed and the `self.view.frame.size.width` value is `768`.

I have tried a lot of different things to solve this, like putting the contents of the method inside the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` and `viewDidAppear:` methods, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assigning `frame` to the `SecondViewController` with the width  coming from an uninitialized variable?

Comment: The `view` of `SecondViewController` sits within `FirstViewController` and has its frame set to `self.view.frame.size.width`.

Comment: Well that's the problem then, you're assigning width of a view that hasn't been initialized yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the method is first called (which is on app startup), the view is
>   completely wrong, and an NSLog output shows the
>   self.view.frame.size.width is equal to 0.0000.

That's probably because the view hasn't been loaded yet. View controllers don't load their views until they're actually needed, which is usually when the views are about to be displayed for the first time. If your code is trying to find the view's width before the view has been displayed, there's a good chance that the view hasn't been loaded. In Objective-C you're allowed to send messages to `nil`, and the result will be 0 or nil, depending on the expected type.

> If I navigate to ThirdViewController, and then back to
>   SecondViewController, the view is correctly displayed and the
>   self.view.frame.size.width value is 768.

That's consistent with the explanation above; once you've displayed your `SecondViewController` view hierarchy, those views will have been loaded, and finding the width of your view is no problem.

Simply accessing the view controller's `view` property should be enough to cause the view hierarchy to be loaded. If you must, then, you can fix your problem by accessing `self.view` before calling `setupHomeScreen`. A much better solution, though, is to set your view's width in the `-viewDidLoad` method of `SecondViewController`, which will maintain the view controller's "lazy loading" behavior (and conserve memory) while still ensuring that your view's width will be set when it's needed.